# GUI cannot add() JLabel to the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am just new to Java.  When I run the program below I get nothing - no `JLabel` is added to the window

```
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;

  public class MainProgram{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("This is the title of the window");//adding the JFrame or window
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//so it really and literally close when we 
    //hit the close button on the window
    frame.setVisible(true);//setting the visibility
    //adding the label
    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("this is a JLabel");
    //adding the label to the window
    label_1.setToolTipText("This is the tool tip");
    add(label_1);
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: `frame.setVisible(true);//setting the visibility` This should be done after all the components have been added. It is typically the last line of code in the `main`..

Comment: You're adding the label to the current program (which I assume extends a JFrame or JPanel), then you're creating another JFrame within your main method and displaying that instead of the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this line

```
frame.pack();
```

try to set a dimension to the jlabel and the frame itself; when using add(Component) don't to forget frame before it, use it as following : `frame.add(yourLabel);`

Comment: Thanks it worked ... How come this worked can you explain it?
Thanks again.

Comment: i'm refering to this post : 
The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes. An alternative to pack is to establish a frame size explicitly by calling setSize or setBounds (which also sets the frame location). In general, using pack is preferable to calling setSize, since pack leaves the frame layout manager in charge of the frame size, and layout managers are good at adjusting to platform dependencies and other factors that affect component size. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22982334/2228261

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is wrong code.

```
public class MainProgram extends { // extends What?
```

But, what you are doing wrong is that you are adding the JLabel to whatever you extend, and not to your `frame`. So, change this line:

```
add(label_1);
```

to

```
frame.add(label_1);
```

Comment: hi Sorry when i copied code to post on stackoverflow i accidently put  extends .. and it does not compile if do 
frame.add(label_1)

Answer (score 0):

You need add your component to your frame `frame.add(label_1);`and set the dimension of your frame