# Not able to display all Buttons on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout, flowlayout

Below is my code. I am not able to add all the 6 buttons. Only Button1 - 3 or Button4-6 are getting displayed at a time.

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

```
// This class contains the main method and launches the Main screen 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LearningHome{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Welcome to the Learning! ");

        try {

        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 800);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true); // Without this property the frame will not be visible

        FlowLayout mainLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        mainPanel.setLayout(mainLayout);

        mainPanel.add(new JButton(" Button 1 "));
        mainPanel.add(new JButton(" Button 2 "));
        mainPanel.add(new JButton(" Button 3 "));

        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();

        subPanel.setLayout(mainLayout);

        subPanel.add(new JButton(" Button 4 "));
        subPanel.add(new JButton(" Button 5 "));
        subPanel.add(new JButton(" Button 6 "));

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel, mainLayout.LEFT);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.add(subPanel, mainLayout.RIGHT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mention the exact layout you seek, and there is a wide number of way to go about arranging components, but to address your specific comment

> I am not able to add all the 6 buttons. Only Button1 - 3 or Button4-6 are getting displayed at a time

1. Add all elements to the `JFrame` before it becomes visible (eg. move the `mainFrame.setVisible(true)` after you add components to `mainFrame`. This way the LayoutManager can arrange the components as needed
2. Consider calling `mainFrame.pack();` prior to calling `setVisible` (see [What does .pack() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982295/what-does-pack-do) )
3. The default `LayoutManager` for the content pane of a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` (default for a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` - so no need to explicitly set the Layout as such)...if you wish to add the two panels so they layout in a line, consider using an appropriate combination of BorderLayout parameters.

For example:

```
mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
mainFrame.pack();//call these methods after adding components
mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

You can alternatively stack them into two lines using the appropriate BorderLayout parameters. For example:

```
mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: PACK was a good option. But with that my page is getting shrink, which I dont need. Apart from that I had implemented everything. Your explanation was awesome. Thank you so much.