# How do I determine the minimum width of a JFrame to hide the horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: java, swing

When I create a JFrame with child components, it opens to the smallest possible width a window can be, when I expected the width to be the minimum size to display the contents of the window without horizontal scroll bars.

How do I determine what that minimum size should be? Obviously *something* in the UI knows, because when made wide enough, the horizontal scroll bar disappears. This is the state I want the window when created. How do I fetch that number, which I suspect I would return as an override to getPreferredSize? As far as a preferred height, that's arbitrary.

Comment: do you 'pack()' the JFrame?

Comment: @MordechayS No, I'm still learning Java and don't know what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I know, when you use the `pack()` method, it automatically chooses the minimum size needed for all the components in-hand.

In [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982295/what-does-pack-do) question, this subject is covered:

> The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or
>   above their preferred sizes. An alternative to pack is to establish a
>   frame size explicitly by calling setSize or setBounds (which also sets
>   the frame location). In general, using pack is preferable to calling
>   setSize, since pack leaves the frame layout manager in charge of the
>   frame size, and layout managers are good at adjusting to platform
>   dependencies and other factors that affect component size.

From [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

Comment: I'll mark the question answered as soon as I can confirm this does the job, though that might just have to wait until Monday...