# Java - Auto Scrollbar by adding more JPanels to parent JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am Creating a Messenger like App just for learning. I set the layout of Parent JPanel to `GridLayout` for Grid.

Now i want JPanel to show ScrollBar when i add more JPanels which exceeds the size of Parent JPanel.

I tried adding it to ScrollPane but its not working
Bellow is an Example image,

Sorry if my Question is not fully explained. I will try to explain it more if needed.

[image]

Comment: You have to set size of the jpanel which added to scrollpane to make it scrollable. Try set size of jpanel bigger tha the size of the scrollpane.

Comment: [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: "I will try to explain it more if needed." The question is clear. Please post your code to see what you tried.

Comment: See an example of using `JScrollpane`   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50421615/3992939)

Comment: BTW - on seeing that image, the first thing I think is `JList`. Use an appropriate rendering component and it could display `Message` objects easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone tried to solve my problem, but in my case it doesn't help me.
So i tried every possible thing i could.

As i saw the `scrollBar` of `JScrollPanel` appears according to the size of `JPanel` so i tried to increase the size of `JPanel` and this solved my problem. Below is an example and explanation of what i said.

After adding all the `JPanels` into the parent `JPanel`, i configured the `height` of parent `JPanel` to {`height` of parent `JPanel` + (`height` of child `JPanel` * `number of msgs`)}

consider the following code:

```
msgPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(268,418+(new msg().getPreferredSize().height*(msgs.length-4)));
```

here the `-4` is the default number of `JPanels` that do can fit in default size of parent `JPanel`

Answer (score 0):

The way i see it, in your case a `BoxLayout` with `Y_AXIS` inside a `BorderLayout` (with a small "trick") would be more elegant. Take a look at the following [SSCCE:](http://sscce.org/) There is a line to comment in order to answer your question, with a grid layout.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class ChatFrame extends JFrame {
    static int x = 1;

    public ChatFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        // Comment the following line to see behavior with grid layout
        gridPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(gridPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        final JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(gridPanel);
        getContentPane().add(sp);

        final String helloWorld = "Hello world, ";
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, e -> {
            ChatPanel cp = new ChatPanel(helloWorld + (x++));
            gridPanel.add(cp);
            // Scroll to the last chat.
            sp.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(sp.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
            gridPanel.repaint();
            gridPanel.revalidate();
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private static class ChatPanel extends JPanel {
        public ChatPanel(String chat) {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
            JLabel chatLabel = new JLabel(chat);
            add(chatLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            // a kind of "trick"
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(getMaximumSize().width, getPreferredSize().height));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ChatFrame().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image]